# Storing an array and objects into another Array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to store an array and other objects as a position in another array?

i.e.

```
ArrayT[] arrayOne = new ArrayT[1];
arrayOne[0] = new ArrayT();

ArrayAtt[] arrayTwo = new ArrayAtt[2];

for(int i = 0; i<arrayTwo.length(); i++){
    arrayTwo[i] = new ArrayAtt();
}

arrayTwo[0].setSomeName("Name");
arrayTwo[1].setSomeSName("SName");

arrayOne[0].setAtt(arrayTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it, since array is just an `Object`. Make an array of `Object`s.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely works. Haven't you run it yet?

Comment: Yup, I have run it I am just trying to fix a problem and making sure that this is correct and now I know it is so Thank you!